# Karma system in Metro: Last Light

Tags: metro-last-light

In Metro: Last Light there are certain events that give you a choice of two outcomes, for example, sometimes you meet people who have "surrendered". You can either leave them be, or kill them. Depending on which choice you take, you get a noise and flash of light (good choice) or the screen goes dark/grayscale (bad choice).

However I have noticed at certain points in the story, there are events that just automatically play the "good choice" event, without a "choice" ever even being presented. For example, when Artyom and Pavel are moving through a crashed plane, Pavel simply says "Look, they're alive!" and then you get the "good choice" event.

So I suppose my question is two part:

- Is there even a "Moral" or "Karma" system in Metro: Last Light?
- What affects it, and what effects does it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a karma system in Metro: Last Light, but it's not called karma, it's called [moral points](http://metrovideogame.wikia.com/wiki/Moral_Points).

It only affects which ending you'll get.

You get moral points by exploring and finding hidden stuff, being stealthy (in certain levels), making the "right" decision (like sparing someone's life) and listening to certain dialogues.

You can find a list of things that increase your moral points further down on the wiki page I linked.